# What advantages does Fly-Mode have over Walk-Mode?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

In comparison, fly mode seems really hard to control, and its style of movement is hard to navigate with. Walk mode feels more controllable, though.

This leads me to the question of does fly mode have its own uses that you can't achieve with walk mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fly mode is a very good option to setup your scene camera animation. When you require a very good walk through or fly By.

Simply select your camera view <kbd>0</kbd> , Click automatic Keyframing and start the fly mode <kbd>Shift + F</kbd>

Don't forget to change the frames.

Comment: Shift+F now starts walk mode by default, you'll need to start fly mode from *3D view > Header > View > Navigation > Fly mode*.

Comment: Oh yes you are correct. Any way. I use to do Camera Animation by using it.

Answer (score 5):

There are some key differences that make fly mode better in some situations.

- Motions are smoother turning and changing direction are not instant, this may be nicer for recording camera animations.
- Speed is handled in a relative manner, so you dont have a fixed speed, it means you can naturally navigate large scenes or a small room in a large scene.
- Some controls are different, MMB pans for example.
- Walk mode isn't compatible with absolute pointing devices, eg - tablets.
- Walk mode uses fixed horizon angle, fly mode allows navigation in all directions with optional z-up alignment.